# Команда видная только отправителю на disnake/discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Видел как некоторые боты показывают сообщение только отправителю, можно реализовать это на disnake/discord.py? Если да прошу написать как, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В discord.py маловероятно ибо он уже не поддерживается

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать эфемерные сообщения, но только с кнопками или слеш командами

```
interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)
```

документация по interaction : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse